# Building the qt_widgets crate fails with "only Qt 5 is supported" but I have both Qt 5.15 and Qt 4.8 installed

Tags: linux, qt, rust

**[SOLVED]** Qt version in qtchooser was 4. All work after version changing.

I recently tried to use Qt in Rust. When I add `qt_widgets` to my dependencies, I get an error:

```
error: failed to run custom build command for `qt_widgets v0.5.0`

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `/home/alex/first/target/debug/build/qt_widgets-6acdb9fff7eba7cd/build-script-build` (exit code: 1)
--- stderr
[2020-06-23T19:17:50Z ERROR ritual_common::errors] Error:
[2020-06-23T19:17:50Z ERROR ritual_common::errors]    only Qt 5 is supported! "4.8.7" is not supported
```

Qt 5.15.0 and Qt 4.8.7 are installed in my system.

Comment: Did you set up your `PATH` and other environment variables to point at your Qt 5 directory as documented on https://rust-qt.github.io/qt/setting_up/?

Comment: I have no result. Do qt crates support qt 5.15.0?

Comment: According to https://rust-qt.github.io/qt/ (at the bottom): no, up to 5.14 only. But Qt is good at backwards compatibility within major versions, so if the crate doesn't hardcode the supported version, perhaps it can be made to work with 5.15.